# Winium- Locate elements not having name or automationId for desktop automation

Tags: automation, locate, winium, ui-spy

I am working on winium for a new use case regarding desktop automation. The problem I face is to identify those elements which don't have a name, class name or automation ID. I am using Inspect.exe and UISpy to locate elements on the desktop.

I tried googling, but didn't find an answer to locate such elements. 
How can I locate such elements?

Answer (score 0):

There are two strategies to locale UI elements:

1. using names, class, IDs like you mentioned.
2. using visual recognition (based on component appearance and coordinates)

In the case of the second strategy, take a look at the following tools:

- [BotCity Framework](https://github.com/botcity-dev/botcity-framework-core-python)
- [Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/)

Using these tools you can navigate in the interface based on UI elements appearance:

[image]